# Choose a contact and fill it in EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I develop an app in android and I want when to press a button opens the contacts and choose one name and fill that name in EditText .. just like the SMS message.

[image] here my code it just open the contact and when I choose the name it's going nowhere!

```
   addto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(it, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: get a contact from the list and add this into tagview  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7582 and get the contact from here https://www.android-examples.com/get-pick-number-from-contact-list-in-android-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

You can get contact information in onActivityResult() method inside your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_CONTACT:
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    //Get number and name from cursor
                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                     //set number and name in editext
                    etName.setText(contactName);
                    etNumber.setText(number);
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the onActivityResult in same activity to get the img info , so when i use it twice shows an error

Comment: for image info you will have different request code in the same onActivityResult